# I want to download the pdf from a url and print it automatically in javascript or react Js particularly . Is there any way?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

PrintJs package is also not working. if there is any other way either by some package or downloading the file to local storage of browser Do suggest.

Comment: Please, show what you tried so far with some code example, so that people can help you.